# Famous datasets that fits well with Mixture Models

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some "famous" (i.e. citable as a paper) datasets that has been successfully fitted by a Mixture Model of any kind. Ideally, it would be better if such paper also have a link to a github repository with the code used to run the experiments.

Answer (score 1):

As today, I have found:

- Speaker verification (Thanks to [this](https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2017/11/14/spoken-speaker-identification-based-on-gaussian-mixture-models-python-implementation/) link):

  - Douglas A. Reynolds, Thomas F. Quatieri, and Robert B. Dunn, “Speaker Verification Using Adapted Gaussian Mixture Models”, M.I.T. Lincoln Laboratory, 2000
  - Najim Dehak et al., “Front end Factor Analysis for Speaker Verification”, IEEE transaction on Audio, Speech and Language Processing, 2010
  - Github Repo: [here](https://github.com/abhijeet3922/Speaker-identification-using-GMMs)